# Can't persist wireless connection Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless

I keep having troubles with wi-fi. I used to have no problems with wireless connection than my laptop started to disconnect multiple times during the day. But now I can see all the wi-fi networks, I try to connect but the connection fails every time. My laptop is Dell Inspiron with Ubuntu 14.04. I reinstalled Ubuntu about 3 months ago, but I didn't have any troubles with wi-fi after re-installation.
I tried to reinstall drivers but it didn't help at all.

`iwconfig wlan0` command output

```
wlan0 
IEEE 802.11abgn ESSID:"WiFi #9"
Mode:Managed Frequency:2.412 GHz Access Point:74:D0:2B:5B:0A:F0
Bit Rate=65 Mb/s Tx-Power=22dBm
Retry long limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
Power Management:off
Link Quality=16/70  Signal level=-94 dBm
Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid flag:0
Tx excessive retries:169  Invalid misc:35  Missed beacon:0
```

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; uname -r command` result

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless Ac 3160 [8086: 8470]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:06b0]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
3.13.0-141-generic
```

**EDIT:**
`nmcli dev wifi list` command output

```
SSID                              BSSID               MODE             FREQ       RATE       SIGNAL   SECURITY   ACTIVE  
'TOTOLINK N300RT'                 78:44:76:C3:85:F0   Infrastructure   2412 MHz   54 MB/s    25       WPA WPA2   no      
'netis_5G_D1520D'                 E4:BE:ED:D1:52:12   Infrastructure   5220 MHz   54 MB/s    22       WPA WPA2   no      
'WiFi #9'                         74:D0:2B:5B:0A:F0   Infrastructure   2462 MHz   54 MB/s    22       WPA2       no      
'HOME'                            78:44:76:C4:C5:B4   Infrastructure   2412 MHz   54 MB/s    17       WPA2       no      
'Vanechka'                        E4:BE:ED:D1:52:0D   Infrastructure   2437 MHz   54 MB/s    17       WPA WPA2   no
```

Comment: What is the result from terminal for `modinfo iwlwifi`  I am sure Dell uses some dkms package based on backports for that wifi to work with a 3.13 kernel

Comment: I am quite surprised by the link quality. How close are you to the router? Has an antenna wire become dislodged?

Comment: @chili555 Practically in 2 meters from it. BTW the internet works completely fine on other devices

Comment: I meant the antenna wire on the wireless card, not the router. Are all signal strengths very low? `nmcli dev wifi list` I am about three meters from my router and my signal strength is 58/70.

Comment: @chili555 I have added command result. All signals are indeed very low

Comment: I suggest that you check the antenna wires on the card. Be certain they are securely snapped in place: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/517%2BoBOLEaL._SY355_.jpg Check both #1 and #2.